# Copy files using an input file to read file directions

Tags: shell, grep, find, pipe, cp

I'm using `grep` to search through 1 TB of files. I want to grep filenames and put the names in a text file AND I want to `cp` all files with a match to the dir `/home/user/matches`. I want to both tasks without searching through all my files with grep twice.

I had the idea to put filenames output into a text file with grep

```
grep -ril "xxx" . >> /home/user/matches/output-filename.txt
```

And now use `output-filename.txt` as input for cp and make cp execute line per line. How do I do that? awk? Or do you guys have other ideas to avoid searching through all files twice

Comment: Hard to tell what you are trying to do. However is looks like a job for `xargs` and `tee`.

Comment: What do you mean by "directions" in the title?  All the copying is *to* the same directory, not bidirectional according to some specification.  Maybe just just meant reading paths (filenames) to copy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File paths are sequences of bytes other than 0; they're not necessarily text let alone lines of texts. In particular, a file path

- may contain newline characters
- may contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters
- may be longer than LINE_MAX

The GNU implementation of `grep` (the one that added the `-r` option), can print the paths in a non-text format with `-Z` that is post-processable safely. For instance, GNU `xargs` can process that format with its `-0` option:

```
xargs -r0 -a <(
  grep -rilZ xxx . |
   tee file.list
)  cp -it /home/user/matches --
```

(here also assuming GNU `cp` for its `-t` option)

If you want to print that list in a text¹ format that is understandable by a human, with GNU `printf`:

```
xargs -r0a file.list printf '%q\n'
```

---

<sup>¹ Well, it should ensure bytes that can't be decoded as characters are rendered as `$'\234'` representations. Same for control characters including newline, which is rendered as `$'\n'`. That addresses the first two points above, but it doesn't guarantee the output will have lines shorter than `LINE_MAX` (but then again, GNU implementations of standard text utilities generally don't have a limit on length of lines they support).</sup>

Comment: Is `--reflink=auto` the default for `cp`?  If not, specifying it explicitly will save a lot of I/O if the files are on the same filesystem, and the FS supports reflinks (like BRTFS).  (I'd normally have used `ln` for something like this, although that does disturb the ctime on each of the files being linked; that's an advantage for making reflinks.)

Comment: @PeterCordes see [Why is cp --reflink=auto not the default behaviour?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/80351). Using reflink or not is rather orthogonal to this Q&A so I'll leave it out. Your comment is still useful though.

Comment: Ok, good, it finally is the default, many years after the option was introduced.  (In coreutils 9.0, the first major release since that 2013 question).  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `find` with a chained pair of `exec` commands. Perhaps not the most efficient solution as it invokes `grep` for every file (and `cp` for every matched file), but it will work regardless of the characters in the file name:

```
mkdir -p ~/matches
find -type f -exec grep -il 'xxx' {} \; -exec cp -p {} ~/matches/ \; > ~/matches/output-filename.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this using [`tee`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html), [`xargs`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) commands (using `NULL byte \0` as end of filename separator) and [`GNU grep`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

Handle filenames with spaces, newlines etc...

```
mkdir -p ~/matches
grep -Zril "xxx" . |
    tee ~/matches/output-filename.txt |
    xargs -0 -I {} cp {} ~/matches/
```